# Using parse in Quasar (vue) to fetch data from data - return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parse-platform, quasar

Im using [parse.js](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) for pulling data from database in SPA build in Quasar (based on vue.js). Im getting data undefined when fetching data from my database when calling the data through a method but it works when I put it straight into the create function. I guess they might be in different scopes (?) but I cannot figure out why.

This works:

```
export default {
  name: "MyPage",
  data() {
    return {
      myData: []
    };
  },

  created: async function() {
    let query = new parse.Query("TheData");
    const results = await query.find();
    this.myData = results;
    console.log(this.myData);
  }
```

But when I encapsulate the data into a method it returns

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'myData' of undefined

```
export default {
  name: "MyPage",
  data() {
    return {
      myData: []
    };
  },

  created: async function() {
    this.getTheData();
  },
  methods: {
    getTheData: async () => {
      let query = new parse.Query("TheData");
      const results = await query.find();
      this.myData = results; // TypeError: Cannot set property 'myData' of undefined
      console.log(this.myData);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you try changing this

```
created: async function() {
  this.getTheData();
}
```

for

```
async mounted() {
    this.getTheData();
}
```

According to the documentation it says:

> Don't use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> created: () => console.log (this.a) or vm. $ watch ('a', newValue =>
> this. myMethod ()). Since an arrow function doesn't have a this, this
> will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through
> parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught
> TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError:
> this.myMethod is not a function.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks